# Adding offline functionality to Commerce POS

Tags: commerce

I'm looking into using drupal commerce on drupal 8 to make a custom pos. I'm also using the commerce pos module. One of the features required is a limited offline functionality. 
As mobile terminals frequently loose net connectivity having the ability to process orders offline and then push those orders to the central commerce site is a must.

Short of using an external pos application or completely removing the pos module and creating a react app is there a way to add some sort of offline functionality to the existing commerce pos ?